# How to prevent EMI from affecting transistor

Tags: transistors, rf, emi-filtering

I am working on a simple APRS tracker.

The schematic is here:

[image: Schematic]

It's not on a PCB, but just on a protoboard:

[image: Board]

The problem:

Q1 transistor activates the push-to-talk on a handheld VHF transceiver, "analog out" outputs the signal. All of this works fine, except once the signal is transmitted, the push-to-talk remains open - the transistor malfunctions.

It was suggested this might be due to EMI. I lowered the transmit power and wound the cable leading to the HT around a ferrite.

Indeed this solved the problem and everything worked perfectly, but only on the lower power setting (1W). I need to transmit at 7W - the ferrite does no good there.

My question is what can I do to prevent EMI problems with the transistor and the board in general?

I tried putting the board in a thin (and light) aluminium housing, which did little. I do have some weight constraints for this projects and the transmitter has to be in very close proximity to the board as well.

Any ideas or insights would be appreciated

Comment: What is the interface circuit inside the VHF transceiver the relates to the PTT connection you have made? Is the arduino still operational when the PTT off signal fails or does it reset?

Comment: Hello Andy - I guess you can see it in the middle of the schematic - https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/BaofengSchematic_Large.jpg  .And about the Arduino - it's seemingly still operational, it will be difficult to interface it with a UART to debug, while it's wired to work with the VHF HT